# Why are these indices not getting the same thing from a 2d malloc'd C array?

Tags: arrays, c, indexing

Data file I am reading from:

```
$ cat temp.txt
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
```

C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){
    int matsize = 12;
    int numrows = 3;
    int numcols = 4;
    int** mat=malloc(matsize*sizeof(int*)); 
    for(int i=0;i<numrows*numcols;++i){
        mat[i]=malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("temp.txt", "r");
    for(int i = 0; i < numrows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numcols; j++) {
            if (!fscanf(file, "%d", &mat[i][j])) 
                break;
            }
        }
    fclose(file);
    printf("%d\n",mat[numrows-1][numcols-1]);
    printf("%d\n", mat[2][3]);
    printf("%d\n", mat[1][5]);
    printf("%d\n", mat[0][11]);
    printf("Done allocating.\n");
}
```

```
$ ./a.out 
11
11
0
7
```

The first two outputs are both 11 as expected. For a 12 item array, I was expecting `mat[1][5]` and `mat[0][11]` to output the same thing as `mat[2][3]` (i.e. the 12th element, i.e. the [i+1th][j+1th] element). My understanding is that internally, the array declared here:
`int** mat=malloc(matsize*sizeof(int*));`
is not *really* a 2x3 array, rather it's just a `matsize` array and that accessing it via `mat[i][j]` just kind of divides it into [i] rows then gets the [jth] element of the ith row. Does the compiler "know" the array should be a 3x4 array because I am reading the text file in with the line `if (!fscanf(file, "%d", &mat[i][j]))` ? Does this scanning statement permanently change the `mat` object into 3 pointers of 4-length integer arrays? Or is it really just still a 12-length array, which should be accessible via dividing into two 6's, one 12, etc (if so, then why didn't the last two indexings print out the right thing)?

Follow up: If I change everything from %d/ints to %lf/doubles, I get this output with the same indexing:

```
11.000000
11.000000
9.000000
11.000000
```

Why is, for example, `mat[0][11]` coming out to 7 when everything is an int, but `11.000000` (as expected) when things are floats?

Comment: Why you need double pointer to allocate single `int` at the end? The pointer `mat[i]` can keep the int value instead of pointer to int.

Comment: To preserve the 2d structure of the data, I suppose? Is it better practice to use a single pointer and then make some function to map the 2d indices to a 1d index?

Comment: You first `malloc` must be `malloc(numrows * sizeof(int*))` and then `mat[i]=malloc(numcols * sizeof(int))`. PS: Don't forget to `free` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allocate a 2D array instead. It can be done as

```
int (*mat)[rows][cols] = malloc( sizeof(int[rows][cols]) );
```

However, to enable the conventient `mat[i][j]` syntax, you have to drop one of the dimensions in the pointer type:

```
int (*mat)[cols] = malloc( sizeof(int[rows][cols]) );
```

Not only does this get rid of the needless complexity and bugs, it also enables you to read the whole file with a single `fread` call, since you have a real 2D array now, instead of some fragmented pointer-to-pointer thing.

Don't forget the `free(mat);` at the end.